# mv says files are the same name

Tags: linux, mv

When I try to move `/var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu/wordpress` to `/var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu/` I am getting an error message saying the files have the same name.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: @Jesse_b it wouldn't have hurt the op to state it, but a simple `mv <from> <to>` immediately results in the error described.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: hah, duh...I didn't even realize it was the same directory

Comment: I am using sudo mv/var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu/wordpress /var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish by moving something to the directory it's already in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When moving a file (or directory, which essentially is a file as well) to a directory that exists, it will attempt to move it there without changing the name of the file. So, in your example, implicitly the following is happening.

```
mv /var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu/wordpress /var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu/wordpress
```

This of course is the same file, and that is why you get that error message.

Comment: I am using sudo mv/var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu/wordpress /var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu

Comment: sorry I misread this...so what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: @AaronJCarrillo What is it you are trying to do? Currently, you are trying to move the wordpress file/directory to the location it is already in.

Comment: so that is an example server actually but the same concept.  The thing is, I am trying to finish up an assignment in which the instructor isn't much help.  The Wordpress setup is supposed to come up when i go to my site juno-vh.lt.unt.edu  when I go there it only shows me an appache test page.  When I got to juno-vh.lt.unt.edu/wordpress it is showing what it is supposed to.  I believe I just need to move that one level up but I am very lost and not sure what I am doing on this part at this point.

Comment: @AaronJCarrillo You indeed want to move all your files up one level then. You can issue the following command from the `/var/www/html/poseidon-vh.lt.unt.edu/` directory: `mv wordpress/* wordpress/.[!.]* wordpress/..?* .` and then `rmdir wordpress`